# What is the issue in the line "CREATE DATABASE Keys(" MYSQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

I was writing a MySQL table create statement when I encountered the following error with the following code:

```sql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'Keys( id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ip VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, email VA' at line 1
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Keys(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ip VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

This code follows all MySQL guidelines as far as I know.
Could anyone help me find out the error here?

Thanks!

I attempted to plug the code into various SQL syntax checkers and linters and I found the same error in all of the ones I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KEYS` is a MySQl reserved word, so the table name needs escaping. (Or changing, so this doesn't come up every time you make a query.)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

```
CREATE TABLE `Keys`(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the use of the word "Keys" as the name of the table. "Keys" is a reserved keyword in SQL, which means it cannot be used as a table name without being enclosed in backticks. To fix the error, you should enclose the table name in backticks like this:

CREATE TABLE

> `Keys`

(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
ip VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);